# How to combine different counts in one SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count, union-all

I would like to combine different Count statements in one query so that in the end the query just returns one number (total) for each Count.

The following queries work separately but I could not find a way to combine them without repeating the same result (nested tables) and without losing the separate names for each of them (Union All).

My SQL (just combined for easier view here):

```
(
    SELECT      COUNT(*) OVER() AS countB
    FROM        MOC_Log2 B
    WHERE       B.modBy = @modBy
    AND         B.lastUpdate = 'Added'
    FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
),
(
    SELECT      COALESCE(SUM(D.vote), '0') AS countC
    FROM        MOC_Log3 C
    LEFT JOIN   MOC_Log3_Votes D
    ON          D.itemID = C.itemID
    WHERE       C.modBy = @modBy
    AND         C.lastUpdate = 'Added'
    FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
),
(
    SELECT      COALESCE(SUM(F.vote), '0') AS countE
    FROM        MOC_Log4 E
    LEFT JOIN   MOC_Log4_Votes F
    ON          F.itemID = E.itemID
    WHERE       E.modBy = @modBy
    AND         E.lastUpdate = 'Added'
    FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add null columns?

```
SELECT      COUNT(*) OVER() AS countB,
            Null AS  countC,
            Null AS countE
FROM        MOC_Log2 B
WHERE       B.modBy = @modBy
AND         B.lastUpdate = 'Added'
FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
Union
SELECT      null,
            COALESCE(SUM(D.vote), '0'),
            null
FROM        MOC_Log3 C
LEFT JOIN   MOC_Log3_Votes D
ON          D.itemID = C.itemID
WHERE       C.modBy = @modBy
AND         C.lastUpdate = 'Added'
FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
Union
SELECT      null,
            null,
            COALESCE(SUM(F.vote), '0')
FROM        MOC_Log4 E
LEFT JOIN   MOC_Log4_Votes F
ON          F.itemID = E.itemID
WHERE       E.modBy = @modBy
AND         E.lastUpdate = 'Added'
FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
```

Also note I used Union over Union all. It is hard to tell if this would work for you as I cannot tell if the extra null columns may cause some error.

Comment: This works great - thanks a lot for the interesting workaround ! :)